# Does corrosion of metals depend on electron degeneracy pressure?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, conductors, metals

Corrosion is about losing electrons for the corroded metal and gaining electrons for the oxidising substance.

Is it correct to assume that what controls this process is the electron degeneracy pressure?

Comment: Interesting question. It gives me an image of corrosion (and other chemical activity of the metal) being caused by electron gas leaking out of the metal. I suspect it's more complicated because there isn't a simple correlation between conductivity and chemical activity. But there's some relevant info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model

Comment: No. Alkali metals have a low electron density yet are highly reactive with oxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot delete this answer, I will edit it to report that according to @pieter it is wrong.

Comment: glad to do it!!

Comment: Wrong. At any temperature where a substance can exist as a metal, the conduction electrons are a degenerate Fermi gas.